# Wordpress Uncaught ReferenceError: FastClick is not defined

Tags: wordpress, date, datepicker, contact-form-7

I install and active WordPress date picker plugin to active date picker in my contact form 7

I am getting and issue in console Wordpress Uncaught ReferenceError: FastClick is not defined.

**App.js**

```
"use strict";
jQuery(function() {
    return FastClick.attach(document.body), $(".back-to-top").on("click", function(t) {
        return t.preventDefault(), $("html,body").animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, "500", "swing")
    }), $(window).scroll(function() {
        return $(window).scrollTop() >= 80 ? $("header").addClass("after-scroll") : $("header").removeClass("after-scroll")
    }), $(window).width() > 1024 ? $.stellar({
        horizontalScrolling: !1,
        verticalOffset: 100
    }) : void 0
});
```

Comment: I imagine that fastclick is not defined

Comment: Yes, What is the solution for this .?

Comment: make sure that you have it defined

Comment: Due date for materials? the field in this Link. https://shmarinas.com/marketing/

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but it looks like it expects this to be present: https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick

Comment: i don't find anything related there, I should add a fastclick.js script to my Wordpress Page.do you have any idea about that .?

Comment: not sure; I'm just guessing from the name. If you do add it, make sure that it loads before it's called. The code calling fastclick is from the theme btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrap your plugin in the following line, jquery has the jQuery namespace in wordpress

```
(function($){
//the plugin js code
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the plugin could just be constructed poorly, or that some other plugin is dequeuing the FastClick script (for whatever weird reason that would be...), so that dependency is just gone.

If you're comfortable, one option would be to try to enqueue FastClick...

```
 wp_enqueue_script('fastclick', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fastclick/1.0.6/fastclick.min.js', array(), false, true);
```

You just need to make sure it's loaded before this plugin's scripts, so it can actually reference it and know it exists.

That said, this plugin sounds messed up. I wouldn't use it.

Comment: Where i have to use this Script.? in functions.php

Comment: Yes, but you need to place it in a hook for it to execute correctly. https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/adding-scripts-and-styles-wordpress-enqueueing/

Comment: Yes, i Included Script in functions.php Now it's throwing an error. `Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function`. Means Jquery is Missing Right.

Comment: which version of Jquery is recommended .?

Comment: Tough to say, depends on what FastClick requires. I would start by just adding jQuery as a dependency when you enqueue it: 

wp_enqueue_script('fastclick', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fastclick/1.0.6/fastclick.min.js', array('jquery'), false, true);

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when you use cache or the jQuery loaded before fastclick JS then as we have to load it on body then we can use a `windows.load` function

```
window.onload = function() {
//code goes here
}
```

In my case I'm using the fastclick JS in child theme `footer.php`.